# Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllLists() with Async

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My function looks like this:

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllLists() {
    late String temp = "name";

    getUserSortMethod().then((value) => {
          temp = value.toString(),
          // temp is now "prio"
        });

    return firestore
        .collection('lists')
        .where('editors', arrayContains: currentUser.email)
        .orderBy(temp, descending: false)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I need to wait for the result of getUserSortMethod() to use it in return. How can I use return and before that wait for result of getUserSortMethod function?

Tried to change main function to async return to

```
 Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>> but get not working.
```

Comment: see https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller and / or https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch

Comment: you can also use [StreamCompleter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/StreamCompleter-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using async method but the method declaration doesn't mention as async. In your sample code you don't have `await` due to that firestore order will be done by name always. Because before completing the async operation it will return the snapshot.

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllLists() async {
    late String temp = "name";

    // use await here because you need temp value updated by getUserSortMethod async function.
    temp = await getUserSortMethod();

    return firestore
        .collection('lists')
        .where('editors', arrayContains: currentUser.email)
        .orderBy(temp, descending: false)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Otherwise run the `getUserSortMethod` async function then pass the result to `getAllList` Function.

Answer (score 0):

this works very well:

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllLinks(String listName) async* {
print('### LLFireDataSource::getAllLinks:' + currentUser.email.toString());
var sort = await getUserSortMethod();
yield* firestore
    .collection('items')
    .where('list', isEqualTo: listName)
    .orderBy(sort, descending: false)
    .snapshots();
```

}